# How to get the If Else to work on click?

Tags: jquery

```
$(cell).click(function(){
  var cellColor = $(this).css("background-color");

  if(cellColor != "red"){
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
  }else{    
    $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
  }
});
```

Hi,

Why isn't the else statement working here please when clicking on the same cell again (i.e. the background of the cell has turned into red on first click as intended)?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery returns color codes not by names, but RGB - http://jsfiddle.net/cHWxv/

```
$("div").click(function(){
  var cellColor = $(this).css("background-color");

    alert(cellColor);

  if(cellColor != "rgb(255, 0, 0)"){
    $(this).css("background-color", "rgb(255, 0, 0)");
  }else{    
    $(this).css("background-color", "rgb(0, 0, 255)");
  }
});​
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I thought after running a bug test.

Answer (score 0):

What is 'cell' for element? Maybe the element doesn't support the background-color style?

Try with firebug in firefox to debug your JS-code, to see what the exact value is.

Check jquery docs about css-function http://api.jquery.com/css/. Especially this paragraph:

"....  jQuery understands and returns the correct value for both .css('background-color') and .css('backgroundColor'). Different browsers may return CSS color values that are logically but not textually equal, e.g., #FFF, #ffffff, and rgb(255,255,255).... "